# What to do for "Login attempt failed for admin." and "Access denied" to path admin?

Tags: security, log-messages

In Watchdog, I started seeing several entries like this:

> Login attempt failed for admin.

And

> access denied 2016/04/04 - 15:06  admin

These are generating a fair number of log entries.  The IP address is different for each request; they all geolocate to Russia.

Obviously, this is not me, and there doesn't appear to be any particular danger to my site, but is there a way to minimize such requests?

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to prevent those entries from showing up in Watchdog? I think this is good - if the issue escalates and you see 100 such requests per hour, you'll be able to deal with it faster and before it influences your site (e.g. performance hit).

Comment: For extra security (for admin) look at https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_by_ip

Comment: @AramBoyajyan Good point, badly phrased question.  I'm interested in addressing/minimizing the requests rather than just removing the watchdog entries.

Comment: How about 'Discard access logs older than' set very tight, and then some form of non DB backup for historical purposes, such as https://www.drupal.org/project/watchdog_digest or just a module to backup watchdog regularly, ie https://www.drupal.org/project/2697397/git-instructions?

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can rename path to login page, you can try [Rename Admin Paths module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths) to do it.